# Tabulator - addColumn() returned promise

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a Tabulator table that has a number of 'standard' columns, which are defined at the time of defining the table.
I also have a number of 'custom' columns, which are programmatically added to the table after it is built, using table.addColumn() method.
After each 'custom' column is added, I want to iterate through its cells, so that I can do some formatting based on some data in one of the 'standard' columns.
The .addColumn() method returns a promise, so I'm using .then() to do that formatting after the custom column is added.

The code below shows how I do this, and the example below works as expected. However, when I implement this algorithm in my own app, I get the following error:

```
ComponentFunctionBinder.js:27 The row component does not have a getIndex function, have you checked that you have the correct Tabulator module installed?
```

Here is my algorithm:

```
myTableData = [
    {'myID':'id1', 'column1':'col1data1', 'colum2':'col2data1', 'customField1':'customField1Data1', 'customField2':'customField2Data1', },
    {'myID':'id2', 'column1':'col1data2', 'colum2':'col2data2', 'customField1':'customField1Data2', 'customField2':'customField2Data2', },
]

myCustomFields = [
    {'field_id':'customField1', 'field_name':'Custom Field 1'},
    {'field_id':'customField2', 'field_name':'Custom Field 2'},
]

myTable = new Tabulator("#assetsTable", {
    height: "600px",
    data: myTableData,
    columnDefaults:{tooltip:true, hozAlign:'center', headerHozAlign:'center', headerFilter:'input', sorter:'alphanum', sorterParams:{alignEmptyValues:"bottom"}},
    index:"myID",
    columns:[
        {title:"my ID", field:"myID"},
        {title:"Standard Column 1", field:"column1"},
        {title:"Standard Column 2", field:"column2"},
    ]
});

myTable.on('tableBuilt', function(){
    for (let myCustomField of myCustomFields){

        myTable.addColumn({
            title:myCustomField.field_name,
            field:myCustomField.field_id,
        }).then(function(column){
            let cells = column.getCells();
            for (let cell of cells){
                let rowData = cell.getData()  // does not return all the data that I'm expecting.
                console.log('row index is', cell.getRow().getIndex());  //triggers Tabulator error.
                //do some formatting stuff based on other 'standard' fields in the row.
            }
        })
    }

});
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve what I'm trying to do? Note, the 'custom' columns are being added programmatically because the field_id and field_title are based on other data entered by the user.

Comment: @DerekPollard isn't that the same as what the .then() does?

Comment: How are you loading Tabulator in your project?  Is it imported as module? Using a locally hosted version in a script tag? CDN?

Comment: @Timur I'm loading it using the CDN-UNPKG described in the Tabulator documentation (version 5.4.2).

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure then since the example you posted works fine on my end.  As an option, you can try to pass a custom formatter at the time of adding the columns instead of waiting for the promise.